# Jquery Tablesorter not working for Date column dd-mmm-yyyy in Internet explorer 10

Tags: jquery, date, tablesorter

I have a table that has four columns and the fourth column is the date column in the format dd-mmm-yyyy. I have tablesorter plugin installed in my Java application. I have rewritten the parser for shortdate like below,

```
ts.addParser({
    id: "shortDate",
    is: function (s) {

        return (/^(\d{1,2}|\d{4})[\/\-\,\.\s+](\d{1,2}|(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))[\/\-\.\,\s+](\d{1,2}|\d{4})$/).test(s);
    }, format: function (s, table) {
        var c = table.config;
        //s = s.replace(/\-/g, "/");
        s = s.replace(/\s+/g," ").replace(/[\-|\.|\,]/g, "/");
        if (c.dateFormat == "us") {
            // reformat the string in ISO format
            s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{4})/, "$3/$1/$2");
        } else if (c.dateFormat == "uk") {
            // reformat the string in ISO format
            s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{4})/, "$3/$2/$1");
        } else if (c.dateFormat == "dd/mm/yy" || c.dateFormat == "dd-mm-yy") {
            s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{2})/, "$1/$2/$3");
        } else if (c.dateFormat == "dd-mmm-yy") {

            var months = {Jan:1, Feb:2, Mar:3, Apr:4,May:5,Jun:6,Jul:7,Aug:8,Sep:9,Oct:10,Nov:11,Dec:12};
            s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\s](Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[\/\s](\d{2,4})/, function(str,p1,p2,p3) { if (parseInt(p3)>60) {p3='19'+p3;}else{p3='20'+p3;}return p3 + "/" + months[p2] + "/" + p1;});
        }

        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(new Date(s).getTime());
    }, type: "numeric"
});
```

The parser works well in Mozilla and Chrome but not for the date column alone in the IE 10. Other columns are getting sorted in IE.

I have called my table from my JSP as below on the Javascript onload,

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({
  headers: {
    0: {sorter:"string"},
    1: {sorter:"string"},
    2: {sorter:"numeric"},
    3: {sorter:"shortDate",dateFormat: "dd-mmm-yyyy"} 
  }
});
```

Please let me know where i have the problem.

Comment: Somebody Please help me

Comment: Can you provide an example of some dates in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Just from a quick look - I didn't actually test the parser - set the `dateFormat` in the tablesorter config and not inside a header definition:

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({
  dateFormat: "dd-mmm-yy", // use "yy" not "yyyy"
  headers: {
    0: {sorter:"string"},
    1: {sorter:"string"},
    2: {sorter:"numeric"},
    3: {sorter:"shortDate"} 
  }
});
```

Comment: These are some of the dates,20-Aug-2014

28-Sep-2015

20-Mar-2015

21-Jan-2015

20-Aug-2014

Comment: I have actually added one parser seperately and tested. But no use. I even tried changing the date format to dd-mm-yyyy, i was not able to see the expected sort ascending and descending

Comment: My table has the style from the Twitter Bootstrap
Style name  : table tablesorter table-striped sieve

Comment: Actually, the problem is that the parser is looking for a `dateFormat` of `"dd-mmm-yy"` not `"dd-mmm-yyyy"`... I am assuming you're using the original tablesorter, so I set up [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1433/)